# Check gem version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I want to check the gem version for my app through the Rails console. In my gemfile, I have

```
gem 'rack', '1.2.3'
```

Ran bundle install after. In the Rails console,

```
>> Rack.version
=> "1.1"
```

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

```
Gemfile.lock

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionpack (3.0.9)
      ...
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      ...

    rack (1.2.3)

    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)

    warden (1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1.0)

DEPENDENCIES
...  
rack (= 1.2.3)
...
```

There are several rack versions listed in `gemfile.lock`.

Comment: what about rack version in the `Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: what's the full command you used to run the console?

Comment: @nash, see updated question for details. @kain, `rails console` for dev, `heroku console --app <my app>` for production.

Comment: use bundle exec rails console in local and try again

Comment: @kain, `bundle exec rails console` gives the same output Rack 1.1.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Rack.version
```

will return the protocol version,

```
Rack.release
```

is probably what you are you looking for.

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack.rb#L14

Otherwise:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["rack"]
```

Example:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["rack"]
# => #<Gem::Specification name=rack version=1.3.2> 
Gem.loaded_specs["rack"].version
# => #<Gem::Version "1.3.2"> 
Gem.loaded_specs["rack"].version.to_s
# => "1.3.2"
```

Comment: Thanks Kain, that's exactly what I needed, it returns 1.2.3.

Comment: On a separate note, are you on Rails 3.1 because 3.0.x won't install Rack 1.3.x.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the rails master though, labeled 3.2.0beta

Answer (score 4):

Every gem has ::VERSION constant..
so just use Rack::VERSION or OpenSSL::VERSION in console which should give you the version of gem loaded in that console.

Comment: It's a convention that gems have a VERSION constant on their top-level module, but that doesn't mean it's always true. The top-voted answer is more reliable because gems MUST add a version to their gemspec. See https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/

Answer (score 0):

we can use `bundle list` or `bundle show` to list all Gems included by the bundle.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have multiple version of rack installed, try running `gem uninstall rack` and see if it offers you two options to choose from, Rack 1.1 and Rack 1.2.3. If so, choose to uninstall Rack 1.1.

If this still does not work, just uninstall Rack and try running bundle update.

I had this problem when I was using multiple rake versions 0.8.7 and 0.9.2, this helped me.

Comment: I do have multiple versions of Rack (and rake) installed, but only Rack 1.2.2 and 1.2.3, not 1.1. Is my command checking the Rack version in the console correct?

Comment: Not really sure, never tried that.

Alternatively, you can use this slick trick:

**gem list --local | grep 'rack'**

This should list all your rack versions.